# mapfile and redirection issue

Tags: bash, pipe, command

I would like to redirect the output of a command to input of mapfile.
I'm doing this and it's working:

```
xls2csv -x $files -W -q | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v '^The' > lista.txt
mapfile -t titulos < lista.txt
```

I'm trying to use just one command to achieve this. But none of them are working.

```
xls2csv -x $files -W -q | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v '^The' > mapfile -t titulos
xls2csv -x $files -W -q | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v '^The' | mapfile -t titulos
mapfile -t titulos < <( xls2csv -x $files -W -q | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v '^The' )
```

Comment: The first creates a file called mapfile, the second loses the variable to a subshell (via the pipe); the third looks reasonable to me, though

Comment: @JeffSchaller the third one gives the error "/dev/fd/62: No such file or directory"

Comment: Try to `export files` before execute `<()`. Secondary you can avoid **sed** `-q | grep -ve '^The' -e '^$' )`